# Feature specs fail only on CircleCI or Codeship continuous integration services

Tags: selenium, rspec, capybara, circleci, codeship

My very basic feature specs are passing just fine locally but failing on CircleCI and Codeship. The tests that are failing:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'Authentication' do

  describe "sign in" do
    it "is the landing page for non-authenticated users" do
      user = create(:user)
      visit root_path

      expect( page ).to have_content 'LOG IN' # On sign-in page
      fill_in 'Email', with: user.email
      fill_in "Password", with: user.password
      click_button 'Sign in'

      expect( current_path ).to eq user_path(user)
    end
  end

  describe 'registration' do
    it "allows new users to register" do
      visit root_path

      click_link 'Sign up'
      fill_in 'Email', with: 'myfake@email.com'
      fill_in 'Password', with: 'password'
      fill_in 'Password confirmation', with: 'password'
      fill_in 'First name', with: 'John'
      fill_in 'Last name', with: 'Doe'
      click_button "Sign up"

      expect( current_path ).to include '/users/'
      expect( page ).to have_content "Welcome! You have signed up successfully."
    end
  end
end
```

The tests both fail on the first lines where they set expectations of the pages (`expect( page ).to have_content "LOG IN"` and `click_link "Sign up"`, respectively), with errors suggesting the page HTML is completely blank:

```
expected to find text "LOG IN" in ""
```

I saved screenshots on CircleCI, and they indeed show a completely blank page.

Here's where it gets interesting. I tried debugging the problem by [running/watching the specs on Circle using a VNC](https://circleci.com/docs/browser-debugging#interact-with-the-browser-over-vnc). When I **a)** set `driver: :selenium` for the tests, **b)** add a `sleep 1` or two to the tests before testing the page expectations, and **c)** manually run the test after SSHing into their servers with the VNC, I can see the tests run in Selenium (they open a browser in the VNC) and they pass perfectly.

Outside of the VNC, however, the tests fail consistently in both CI servers. With or without tons of `sleep`s and `driver: :selenium`. Any ideas what could be causing this discrepancy between the regular CircleCI/Codeship servers and their VCN/my local test environment? I got in touch with the folks at CircleCI, but they're stumped for the moment.

> If relevant, I'm running Ruby 2.2.0, Rails 4.2, Capybara 2.4.4, Capybara-Webkit 1.4.1, and Selenium-Webdriver 2.44.0

Some potentially relevant files:

**spec_helper.rb**

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"

require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)

require "rspec/rails"
require "shoulda/matchers"
require "webmock/rspec"
require 'vcr'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |file| require file }

module Features
  include Warden::Test::Helpers
  Warden.test_mode!

  def sign_in(user)
    login_as(user, scope: :user)
  end
end

module Controllers
  # Pre-parse controller responses for easy access
  def response_body
    body = JSON.parse(response.body)
    body.is_a?(Hash) ? body.to_sh : body.map(&:to_sh)
  end
end

module Mock
  def disable_webmock(&block)
    WebMock.disable!
    yield
    WebMock.enable!
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |c|
    c.syntax = :expect
  end

  # Save a screenshot to CircleCI when a feature test fails
  config.after(:each, :type => :feature) do |example|
    if example.exception
      artifact = save_page
      puts "\"#{example.description}\" failed. Page saved to #{artifact}"
    end
  end

  config.include Features, type: :feature
  config.include Controllers, type: :controller
  config.include Mock
  config.include Formulaic::Dsl, type: :feature
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  config.order = "random"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
end

RSpec::Matchers.define :hash_eq do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    actual.recursive_symbolize_keys == expected.recursive_symbolize_keys
  end
end

VCR.configure do |c|
  c.cassette_library_dir = 'spec/fixtures/vcr_cassettes'
  c.hook_into :webmock
  c.allow_http_connections_when_no_cassette = true
  c.configure_rspec_metadata!
  c.ignore_hosts '127.0.0.1', 'localhost:3000'
end

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit

if ENV['CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS']
  Capybara.save_and_open_page_path = ENV['CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS']
end

WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)
```

**database_cleaner.rb**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

Comment: This might be a CircleCI config problem. Can you share your cicle.yml file as well?

Comment: Are you using headless or a Saas service?  Most of those CI programs are purely headless and can't run something like selenium without some real work.

Comment: If you use selenium, can try with Firefox 28.0.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a couple of things to try:

- If you want to get your specs to run headless, try using poltergeist rather than capybara-webkit. poltergeist has several advantages which I described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24108439/634576
- Selenium might just be a distraction, but, if you want to get it to work, be sure that your CI environment has the right version of Firefox. Each version of selenium-webdriver seems to need a narrow range of versions of Firefox. [On CircleCI, you can configure circle.yml to install a specific version of Firefox.](https://circleci.com/docs/installing-custom-software) Right now we use selenium-webdriver 2.46.2 and Firefox 39.0.3, installed with the following in circle.yml:

  ```
  dependencies:
    pre:
      - sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install firefox=39.0.3+build2-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  ```

  I don't know about Codeship.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced instability of my Selenium tests on CircleCI until I came across this post https://discuss.circleci.com/t/selenium-tests-timing-out/7765/2

After adding:

```
machine:
  environment:
    DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS: /dev/null
```

to my `circle.yml`, my tests have become stable.